# How do I make RouterLinkActive work on children components

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

The app I'm working on has different routes, every time I click on a different route and come back to the route I'm having a problem, RouterLinkActive does not function properly. But If I stay on the Route I'm having problems with and refresh the page RouterLinkActive starts working fine. It only happens when I click on a different route and come back.

`I've read on a different thread to place [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}". I've placed it everywhere and it does not work. Here is an example of the routes and what I have right now written.

```
// Main routing module
// Main routing module
// Main routing module
// The component I'm having problem is inventory path

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },

  {
    path: 'marketplace',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ord-home/ord-home.module').then(m => m.OrdHomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'marketplace/shopping-cart',
    loadChildren: () => import('./shopping-cart/shopping-cart.module').then(m => m.ShoppingCartModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'marketplace/shop',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ord-123/ord-123.module').then(m => m.Ord123Module)
  },
  {
    path: 'ord-history',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ord-history/ord-history.module').then(m => m.OrdHistoryModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'list-manager',
    loadChildren: () => import('./list-manager/list-manager.module').then(m => m.ListManagerModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'standing-orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./standing-order/standing-order.module').then(m => m.StandingOrderModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'inventory',
    loadChildren: () => import('./inventory/inventory.module').then(m => m.InventoryModule)
  },

  { path: 'err', component: DefaultErrorComponent },

  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

```
//Routes on inventory-routing.module

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: InventoryComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: "inventoryManagement", component: InventoryManagementComponent },
      { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
      { path: "sections", component: SectionsComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
//HTML

        <div class="text-center text-white">
          <div type="button" class="navbar-selection" routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="navbar-selected" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Dashboard</div>
          <div type="button" class="navbar-selection" routerLink="inventoryManagement" routerLinkActive="navbar-selected" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Inventory</div>
          <div type="button" class="navbar-selection" routerLink="items" routerLinkActive="navbar-selected" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Items</div>
          <div type="button" class="navbar-selection" routerLink="sections" routerLinkActive="navbar-selected" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Sections</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

`